# How select all unique values from select tag in my situation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code, which select all links, when messenger type includes ['Skype', 'ICQ', 'Jabber']. If user double input skype, need only one first display link on page. How can I add unique links by messenger type?

```
<ul class="list">
      <% @freelancer.links.select {|link| ['Skype', 'ICQ', 'Jabber'].include? link.messenger_type.title }.each do |link| %>
        <li class="list__item data">
          <span class="data__label"><%= link.messenger_type.title %>:</span>
          <span class="data__value"><%= link.url %></span>
        </li>
     <% end %>
    </ul>
```

model Link.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: links
#
#  id                :integer          not null, primary key
#  url               :string
#  freelancer_id     :integer
#  messenger_type_id :integer
#
# Indexes
#
#  index_links_on_freelancer_id      (freelancer_id)
#  index_links_on_messenger_type_id  (messenger_type_id)
#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a unique index to links

```
add_index :links, [:freelancer_id, :messenger_type_id], unique: true
```

Then you should probably validate it in the model too

```
validates :messenger_type_id, uniqueness: { scope: :freelancer_id }
```

Comment: thank you, but why added you  { scope: :freelancer_id }?

Comment: Otherwise it would validate the uniqueness of `messenger_type_id` across the database table.  I.e if you had a skype account then I would get an error if I tried to add one.